# Scalar product in a space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

x−1,2x−1 create a perpendicular and normalised base in a space of polynomials of a degree fewer or equal to one with some scalar product. Find the pattern of this scalar product.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

use the fact hat the vector space of the polynomials $P^{(1)}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic  to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with the correspondence:
$$
a+bx\qquad  \leftrightarrow \qquad (a,b)^T
$$

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you meant, but yes i have three equalities <(1,-1),(2,-1)>=0 <(1,-1),(1,-1)>=1 and <(2,-1),(2,-1)>=1 but where does it lead?